# addItem js_css explanation - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, js-css

To add some css or js file, Magento allow different ways to do that via xml:

Add CSS file:

```
1- <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/custom.css</name></action>
```

```
2- <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/custom.css</stylesheet></action>
```

```
3- <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>folder/custom.css</name></action>
```

Add JS file:

```
4- <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/custom.js</name></action>
```

```
5- <action method="addJs"><script>folder/custom.js</script></action>
```

**Now my question is:**

In the line 3 what is **js_css** ? from what I understood, it is to add css but why we don't add it in `css/` file with all files css `skin/frontend/package/theme/css/` instead of `js/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for JavaScript libraries that bundle their CSS together like many sliders/scrollers do.  For example slick (https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick).